# C++17 Reflection; std::tuple, boost::hana. Возможности и проблемы?

Tags: c++, boost, рефлексия

Всем доброго времени суток.
Сабж в заголовке, а вопрос в следующем:
С помощью кого из данных сверху господ можно максимально близко приблизиться к рефлексии, или даже реализовать возможность автоматической сериализации юзер типов(которые включают как другие юзер типы, так и базовые)?
Заранее спасибо за ответы, советы, рекомендации и ссылки на материал.

Comment: Рефлексии в C++ нет, поэтому всё зависит от конкретной задачи, в условие которой входит в том числе то, что из себя представляют типы, которые нужно сериализовывать. Ваш вопрос, по хорошему, можно закрывать, т.к. он очень сильно неконкретный.

Comment: Не знаю, какими критериями исчисляется корректность того, чего нет. )
А по факту, конкретики для корректности достаточно - автоматическая сериализация(соответственно, итерация по полям с получением их значений.)

Comment: Удобный вариант - взять libclang, распарсить свой код, и вытащить оттуда списке полей/методов всех нужных классов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рефлексия в С++ есть только в минимальных количествах и до адекватной сериализации еще как до луны. `std::tuple` вообще не в тему.

1. Вариант с псевдорефлексией на макросах реализован в `boost.Hana`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

template< typename T >
void serialize(::std::ostream& output, T const & object)
{
    ::boost::hana::for_each
    (
        ::boost::hana::members(object)
    ,   [&](auto const & member)
        {
            output << member << std::endl;
        }
    );
}

struct Person
{
    BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT
    (
        Person
    ,  (::std::string, name)
    ,  (int, age)
    );
};

int main()
{
    Person john{"John", 30};
    serialize(std::cout, john);
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eRWxvoFwlygRYJJk)

2. Вариант с псевдорефлексией на кодогенерации реализован например в Qt MOC.
3. Вариант с псевдорефлексией на дефектах стандарта реализован в [Loophole](https://github.com/alexpolt/luple).

Comment: Ну на макросах и в чистом С рефлексию можно построить :) `V(X,A) X ## A`, в gcc есть например `__builtin_types_compatible_p` и много другого сахара..