# возможно ли сделать макрос для анализа тела функции/структуры?

Tags: c++, c, макросы, метапрограммирование

возможно ли сделать макрос для анализа тела функции/структуры?

К примеру

```
#define my_macros ...

struct Test
{
  my_macros
  int a = 1;
  ...
}
```

что то из этой оперы, чтоб я мог на этапе компиляции разобрать тот текст который находится внутри структуры, или хотя-бы что то отдаленно напоминающее подобный подход?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/925616/c17-reflection-stdtuple-boosthana-%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b/925658#925658

Comment: Похоже, кто то пытается переизобрести Qt с его moc

Comment: Признавайтесь сразу - для сериализации?